# how to edit existing class model with t4 template?

Tags: c#, t4

i have an class model with some properties and need to add piece of code in set section  :

```
class person
{
    string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
            // code
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            //adding here
        }
    }

    // other properties
}
```

how i can do it with  t4 template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The T4 will output the entire file, thus replacing any text present there before.
The way is to generate the entire class in the T4 template.